# Adding horizontal separator / border in fancytree

Tags: jquery, tree, css-selectors, treeview, fancytree

I am using fancytree to create a navigation menu and I need to add a border / horizontal separator. I have tried adding fancytree wide extension, which allows to select the entire row and then added the following to apply css on *init* event:

```
    init: function (event, data) {
                  jQuery("span.fancytree-title").css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
             "border-width":"1px", 
             "border-style":"solid"});
}
```

This results in:

[image]

I need to have a single horizontal separator between the rows. I have explored the markup rendered on fancytree, but can't find a single element covering entire row. Any suggestions will help.

Note: For removing the ticks on the left, I have done following:

```
    jQuery(".fancytree-expander").css('background', 'none');
```

This removed the collapsible ticks on the left side, if there is a better way, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not realy a way to make a separator between the tree items.

However, you can create a styling that mimics that. A couple of solutions I can think of the top of my head:

- During the rendering of the node, render an `<hr />` element at the top or bottom of your element
- Instead of using `border-width, border-color and border-style`, make use of the `border-top` or `border-bottom` variants. You probably have to puzzle a bit with margins and paddings in that case
- Take the margin between the items away and replace it by padding. Then make the border-width half of the original value. Since both lines are drawn against each other, they will look line it is a single line

Some more tips I can give you:

- Avoid using jQuery to set your css rules. Make a separate css file instead. This will improve reusability
- Don't know if you have this link already: http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

There is a Fancytree demo that mimics an accordion look and feel, simply by adding custom CSS rules:
http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-accordion.html

[image: Accordion Demo]

This is not *exactly* what you asked for, but might be a good enough starting point:

```css
/* Display top level nodes as accordion header. */
ul.fancytree-container >li >.fancytree-node span.fancytree-title {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  font-weight: 550;
}
/* Hide  expanders for top-level nodes */
ul.fancytree-container >li >.fancytree-node .fancytree-expander {
  display: none;
}
/* Don't indent level-2 nodes */
ul.fancytree-container >li >ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mar10 I will try to customize this.